# Windows 2019 Server – stuck on Working on updates, 100% complete

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

Good day all, I have a server running Windows 2019 and is stuck on the ‘Working on updates, 100% complete, Don’t turn off your computer’
This server had windows updates which I started yesterday afternoon, then restarted as normal, and since then has been sitting at this screen since yesterday. I have shut down and restarted this computer multiple times to try and get around this issue but nothing has resolved it. I am unable to log into it.

In the meantime, while this is sitting on the console server, the drive maps, DNS, print sharing is all working and the users are having no issues at all.

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, after posting this, I noticed that our external backup drive was connected to one of the USB ports. I pulled the drive and as soon as I did that, the system came back to life with a prompt so all good.